# Female lead is betrayed by her boyfriend and her best friend and gets killed because of that. Then she is reborn to avenge herself

Tags: story-identification, manga

This manhwa is about a female who has power in her necklace (the necklace is like a storage world in which she can store anything), so her boyfriend and her best friend betray her to get the necklace (the boyfriend presents the necklace to the best friend) then leave her to get tortured and raped by a group of boys, and she dies because of all that. She gets reborn to get revenge on them. She also starts to get ready for a coming disaster. (I don't remember what was the disaster clearly, but I think it was a weird creature attacking.) She buys water and other stuff to be prepared for it. There was a general or something from the army who noticed her. He is the male lead.

Comment: Do you remember when you read this? Was it on a comic aggregation site? Fan translation site? Official site dedicated to the comic? Do you remember the hair color of the either of the leads, or what hairstyle they had? Oh, also, do you remember how she got her powers, or whether others had powers?

Comment: I think I read it 4,5, years ago. I don't remember where I read it. but it was comic aggregation site. I don't remember her hair color but it was long(not very long though) other didn't have power (or very few had) I really don't remember much because I lost the sit and forget the name. but I'm dying to read it again

Comment: the power she has was the neckless or a ring and it allows her to storage things

Comment: Can you be clearer about what you mean by the female lead being reborn? Was she reborn as a different person, or did she wake up in her own body some time in the past? Also, was the story set in the modern world, or centuries in the past?

Comment: she get reborn in her own body but before everything (the disaster, and the betray) (its like she returned to the past.) but she still have her memory in the past when she died. The set was in the modern world.

Comment: Do you remember if there's a special reason why she has this magical necklace? Was she using it for anything prior to the betrayal? Is the world otherwise mundane, or is it modern technology + magic? Do you remember anything about the protagonist's background? Is she a high school or university student? Actress or idol? Or anything about her traitor boyfriend?

Comment: I think she had the necklace from the start.( but she didn't know about its power) but the necklace was also one of the reason they betrayed her (after the betrayal the boyfriend gave the necklace to the bestfriend. I'm not sure about their background, but they weren't high school student they were older

Answer (score 1):

This is *[Love and the Apocalypse](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/love-and-the-apocalypse)*. It is licensed by [Bilibili comics](https://www.bilibilicomics.com/detail/mc2435).

> Mu Yiran, an orphan living in the apocalypse, died with hatred in her heart. Unexpectedly, she was reborn back in time and returned to three years before the apocalypse. With her second chance at life, she swore to tear apart the slut and the jack*ss who brought her so much misery. Upon her rebirth, Yiran gained possession of a cultivation dimension. She then started **stockpiling endless supplies and resources. Along the way, she accidentally provoked the strongest militant**.

The opening has her walk in on her friend and boyfriend in bed together. The friend casually reveals that she's just been using her for her storage necklace and elemental powers.

[image: betrayal and mention of the necklace]

Shortly after that the boyfriend pays some men to rape and murder her. She wakes up a few years earlier, before the apocalypse.